# Run Git command in Jenkins multibranch pipeline job

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run Git command to find if a branch already exists or not in a git repo but its obvoius that its failing with error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

This is the command what I am trying to run:

```
def branch_exists_in_angular = sh(script: 'git ls-remote --heads $ANGULAR_REPO $CHECKOUT_BRANCH | wc -l', returnStdout: true)
```

Is there a way I can pass the git ssh key to above command so, it runs well.
Somewhere i find below example:

```
sshagent(['my-git-ssh']){
def branch_exists_in_angular = sh(script: 'git ls-remote --heads $ANGULAR_REPO $CHECKOUT_BRANCH | wc -l', returnStdout: true)
}
```

But it fails saying sshagent is not a valid DSL.

as per suggestion in the comment, I installed ssh agent plugin and tried to run it again... but this time it failed with error:

```
/usr/bin/git: /usr/bin/git: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: do you have the sshagent plugin installed? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin If its installed the step should be available. Can check using the Pipeline Syntax option in a job.

Comment: i just installed sshagent plugin and tried reruning this, but this time it failed with error: /usr/bin/git: /usr/bin/git: cannot execute binary file
any clue?

Comment: Just going to confirm you have the Git plugin installed?

Comment: yes, i have the git plugin installed.

Comment: manually i can run this on server... but through jenkins it fails.

Comment: ok i just read something that suggested it may be user/permissions based. Does the key require a passphrase? does user 'jenkins' have access?

Comment: do i need to do any other configuration/ changes after installing this plugin to make this work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176113/discussion-between-metalisticpain-and-undefined).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379224/if-else-statement-not-working-properly-in-jenkins-pipeline-script-groovy can anyone help me with this?